# How to send authorization header from html to flask

Tags: python, flask, authorization, jinja2, token

I have a project that use flask in backend and jinja and html for frontend.

What i need is to send a request that has an authorization header and all my routes read that header to see if its from an valid user or not?

```
def show_admin():
        data = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        # data = "TOKEN123"
        # واکشی اطلاعات مورد نیاز صفحه داشبورد
        content = {
            'user': mydb.selectalluser(),
            'doreh': mydb.selectalldoreh()
        }
        # چک میشود اگر توکن ارسالی توسط کاربری معتبر است یا خیر
        if str(data) == "TOKEN123":
            return render_template('admin/dashboard.html', content=content)
            # return hello
        else:
            # اگر توکن معتبر باشد صفحه لود خواهد شد
            return render_template('login/index.html')
```

In the if statement it check if the token is valid or not. but...
1. how to generate a request that included Authorization header 
2. how to generate a token for login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the client-side request header (i.e. `Authorization`) on the server-side. IMO, what you want is manage user login/session status, you can implement this with Flask `session`, the information stored on `session` can be obtained between requests (use Cookie):

```py
from flask import session


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    session['token'] = 'TOKEN123'  # store token, use it as a dict
    return 'login success'

@app.route('/admin')
def show_admin():
    if session.get('token') == "TOKEN123":  # get token
        return 'admin page'
    else:
        return 'login page'
```

However, I would recommend using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle user session manganment.

Comment: thanks. what do you suggest for token managing. how to generate token for each login and check if token is valid or not

Comment: Flask-Login will do this for you.